# Azure Policy extension: command 'azureResource.refreshTree' not found

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions, azure-policy

I have installed *Visual Studio Code* (ver 1.14) on Windows 7, and added the extension ***Azure Policy*** (ver. 0.0.22). After signing-in into Azure Cloud by using the *Visual Studio Code* *Azure Account* extension, I try to update the panel in the upper left side of the window in which the resources available in my subscription are listed, unfortunately an error message pops up which says:

```
 command 'azureResource.refreshTree' not found
```

Does anyone has experienced same problem? Any idea about the root cause and how to solve it? 
Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you able to see any resources? Are the policies loading?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. No resources and no policies were listed, although I was logged in. 
Anyway after rebooting Windows (a few days after) the problem has disappeared.

Comment: I had the same kind of issue but than with `command 'azureResource.search' not found.`. After updating and rebooting Visual Studio Code it resolved itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there for a few days till I rebooted Windows. I don't know if this was the real solution of the problem, but it worked for me.